# Missing expected output

Tags: python

I am trying to run this file from the ebook *Learning Python The Hard Way* with the "python ex18.py" command, but it is not outputting anything. What's wrong?

```
# this one is like your scripts with argv
def print_two(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2)

# ok, that *args is actually pointless, we can just do this
def print_two_again(arg1, arg2):
    print "arg1: %r, arg2: %r" % (arg1, arg2)

# this takes just one argument
def print_one(arg1):
    print "arg1: %r" % arg1

# this one takes no arguments
def print_none():
    print "I got nothin'."
```

Comment: You need to call those function first.

Answer (score 8):

Because that file doesn't actually *call* any functions, there's nothing to output.

That file just defines four functions and then does nothing with them. :)

Try adding *calls* to `print_none`, `print_one`, and so forth:

```
print_none()
print_one("hello")
print_two("hello", "world")
print_two_again("hello", "world")
```

Answer (score 3):

Chances are, you aren't calling the function after defining them.

After those methods. Call them eg:

```
print_none()
```

You can either put this at the end of the file, or if you are importing the file in the shell, you can just type it in straight afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining functions, but it doesn't look like you are calling them.

Answer (score 0):

If you come from a C or Java background, "you defined a bunch of functions but have no main loop".